# Mysites User Profiles Gone?

Tags: user-profile, my-site, active-directory

So today suddenly all but the very latest (added within this week) users disappeared from MySites and our People Directory.

What could of caused this to happen? How can I restore everyone's profiles?

I am using SharePoint 2010.

Comment: A couple a things to check. Start with your User Profile Service Application. Is your sync connection working correctly? Start a full profile sync. Did the AD sync account change or password on it change?

Comment: Check with your AD team. Did they change the name of the User OU?

Comment: Nothing with the AD changed... There was however what I would call a "blip" in the network, when stuff suddenly acted strange. It was during this time frame that i lost all those users. I ran a full sync this morning and everyone became visible again... The downside is I had to go through and Exclude multiple accounts again from Employee Directory, and all profile pictures were gone.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a backup of the User profile Databases (Profile DB + Social DB) don't need the sync DB. Once you have restored and configured your UPA, and run the user sync jobs (full + incremental) a few times, query the Profile DB database:

Select * from userprofile_full (nolock) where bDeleted = 1

(Not recommended but I had to do this:

update dbo.UserProfile_Full set bDeleted=0 where bDeleted =1)

The next time the User profile sync job runs it will clear the users that do not exist anymore in AD

Refer to this article: http://rehmanfaiz.blogspot.com.au/2014/01/restoring-user-profile-service.html